# Foreach in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, for-loop, foreach

I want to toggle every second element of a list:

```
s = [False] * 5

for item in s[::2]:
    item = not item

print(s)
```

But it doesn't work.

```
[False, False, False, False, False]
```

This however, works as expected:

```
for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
    s[i] = not s[i]

print(s)

[True, False, True, False, True]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because `item` is a different variable than `list[i]` that happens to hold the same contents (because the `for` loop assigns to `item`). Assigning to `item` will not change `list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you do

```
item = not item
```

What you're actually doing is to change the reference to an object in the array with another reference to an object outside the array. `item` is just a copy of a reference to an object inside the array.

The second code works as expected because it changes the reference in the array itself, not in a reference copy.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
for item in s[::2]:
    item = not item
```

are equivalent to this:

```
for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
    item = s[i]
    item = not item
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're assigning to the variable created during the loop.  In the second you're assigning to an index in the array.  Each iteration of the loop will reset the variable `item`.